# onClick of mail link inside HTML asset how to fire intent to open mail applications in Android

Tags: android

I am loading html characters from asset. I have a mail link there onclick of which I want to fire intent to open mail application. I tried two ways to do this, first I declared mail link as `<a href>` but that won't work unless its a url or a website to visit. Hence, I used below code but no action happening

```
private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if (url.startsWith("mailto:")&&SharedPrefSingleton.read("WebComponent", getString(R.string.empty)).equals(getString(R.string.terms_conditions))) {
                String body = "Enter your Question, Enquiry or Feedback below:\n\n";
                Intent mail = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                mail.setType("application/octet-stream");
                mail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"feedback@lifeontrac.co.in"});
                mail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Feedback");
                mail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body);
                startActivity(mail);
                return true;
            } else {
                view.loadUrl(url);
            }
            return true;
        }


        @Override
        public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
            handler.proceed();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean TextView with links inside then you can add something like:

```
private class BrowserURLSpan extends URLSpan {
    private String url;

    private BrowserURLSpan(String url) {
        super(url);
        this.url = url;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(final View view) {
        if (url.contains("page")) {
            // Paste your code instead of the following.
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                    Uri.parse(BASE_URL.concat("/page.html"))));
        }
    }
}
```

A TextView is set by:

```
    text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text);
    // Your URL here, the example may contain errors.
    text.setText(Html.fromHtml("This is &lt;a href=\"http:\/\/example.com\/page.html\">your link&lt;/a>");
    changeSpannableLinks(text, new URLSpanInterface() {
        @Override
        public URLSpan newInstance(String url) {
            return new BrowserURLSpan(url);
        }
    });
    text.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Where

```
public static void changeSpannableLinks(TextView textView, URLSpanInterface URLSpanInterface) {
    Spannable s = new SpannableString(textView.getText());
    URLSpan[] spans = s.getSpans(0, s.length(), URLSpan.class);
    for (URLSpan span: spans) {
        int start = s.getSpanStart(span);
        int end = s.getSpanEnd(span);
        s.removeSpan(span);
//      span = new URLSpanNoUnderline(span.getURL());
        span = URLSpanInterface.newInstance(span.getURL());
        s.setSpan(span, start, end, 0);
    }
    textView.setText(s);
}

public interface URLSpanInterface {
    URLSpan newInstance(String url);
}
```

Comment: No there is no textview. I have to find a mail link from html asset and then make it as "mail-to" link